# How can I simplify this difference quotient?

Tags: calculus

**(1) $r(t)=3t+\frac5t: \quad \frac{r(t+h)-r(t)}h =\ldots $**

My (incorrect) work=

- **Distribute the 3 to (t+h) in the numerator:**

3(t+h)+[5/(t+h)] = 3t+3h+[5/(t+h)]

- **Find a common denominator for each term in the numerator by multiplying the numerator and denominator by the denominator of the separate fraction:**

I am then left with [(3t^2)+(3h^2)+(6th)+(5)]/(t+h) for the first part of the numerator.
For the second part of the numerator I found a common denominator in the same way, and was left with [(3t^2)+(5)] / t

With the whole numerator I, once again, found a common denominator.

**My result**: [(3t^3)+(6t^2)h+(3th^2)+5t-((3t^3)+5t+(3t^2)h+5h)] / [(t^2)+(th)]

**After cancelling some terms, I am left with this expression:**

[(3t^2)h+(3th^2)-5h] / [(t^2)+(th)]

From here I am unsure about which step to take. As the limit h approaches zero, the function would work since the denominator would not equal zero (if t~=0), but the question specifically asks for it to be as simplified as possible.

Comment: Is this $$r(t)=3t+\frac{5}{t}$$ and $$f(x)=3\sqrt{x}-2$$?

Comment: How would it mean anything differently, @Dr.SonnhardGraubner?  Parentheses are used well to disambiguate any other interpretation, no?

Comment: Yes you have right, i have worked to much today.

Answer (score 1):

In the first we have
$$\frac{r(t+h)-r(t)}{h}=\frac{3(t+h)+\frac{5}{t+h}-3t-\frac{5}{t}}{h}$$
and the second is given by
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{3\sqrt{x+h}-2-(3\sqrt{x}-2)}{h}$$
Can you proceed?
($h\ne 0$)
simplifying the first term
$$\frac{3h(t+h)t+5t-5(t+h)}{(t+h)t}$$

Comment: Thanks for editing my post!

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Just plug in according to the definition to obtain

$$\frac{r(t+h)-r(t)}h = \frac{3(t+h)+\frac{5}{t+h}-\left(3t+\frac5t\right)}{h}$$

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h =\frac{3\sqrt{x+h}-2-\left(3\sqrt{x}-2\right)}{h} $$

and then simplify the expressions.

To give an example and guide to proceed let consider the simpler case $f(x)=\sqrt x$, then we have

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h =\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt x}{h} =\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt x}{h}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x}=$$

$$=\frac{x+h-x}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x)}=\frac{h}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt x}$$

Comment: I think you have to much parantheses in your second equation,

Comment: Fixed the missing parenthesis

Comment: Did you really feel the need to replicate @Dr.SonnhardGraubner's answers?

Comment: @amWhy I was finishing when he published his answer!

Comment: Ok, and is the $3$ on the right place now?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Thanks a lot! Fixed

Comment: Do what any normal, decent user typically does, @gimusi, upon first submitting, and realizing another user already submitted precisely what you just did, without typos.  *Delete your duplicate answer.*  What is the point of submitting a second duplicate answer, even if you did not know someone submitted the same answer prior to you?

Comment: The reason I am having trouble is due to the simplification. I know to substitute in the numerator, but I have tried multiplying by the conjugates, factoring, etc., but WebWork tells me my answers are all incorrect.

Comment: @J98 Let show your work in the OP (not here in the comment but in your original question). I'll take a look to that to give further help and suggestion if I can.

Comment: @J98 I've added a guide for a simpler example in order to show how we need to proceed. Let try with your functions and show your work here.